# Uninstall android app doesn't delete files in documents directory

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

I'm using the Flutter SDK for mobile app development, so far works great.

To the point, I'm using the flutter plugin path_provider (https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider), to create some files over the application's document directory, so using the method 
`getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` gives me the directory and I can create the files I want. My problem is, over Android, when I uninstall the application that folder or the files in that folder doesn't get deleted, so if I install the application again it will detect those files which is not expected.

I have no clue what can be wrong, this is the output of flutter doctor command:

```sh
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.7.8+hotfix.3, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.36.0)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

And just to let you know, the way I retrieve the directory to save is this:

```dart
Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: take a look at this: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/path_provider/lib/path_provider.dart  consider using `getTemporaryDirectory` or `getApplicationSupportDirectory`

Comment: ```getApplicationSupportDirectory``` is only for iOS, however ```getTemporaryDirectory``` seems like the correct one, I will test it

Comment: yes, you're right, `getApplicationSupportDirectory` its only for IOs

Comment: I am using the exact same approach! Did you find a nice solution? I noticed that on some devices the DB stored in getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() gets deleted upon uninstall, and on other devices - it does not.

Comment: I found another neat approach: sqflite has its own getDatabasesPath() method. And if you create the DB there, after uninstall it gets deleted.